# dataframe to json files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with multiple records and I want to create multiple json files based on the column in a dataframe. The files would already be there so I want to append the files.

```
val emp_seq = Seq(("James","Sales","NY",90000,34,10000),
    ("Michael","Sales","NY",86000,56,20000),
    ("Robert","Sales","CA",81000,30,23000),
    ("Maria","Finance","CA",90000,24,23000),
    ("Raman","Finance","CA",99000,40,24000),
    ("Scott","Finance","NY",83000,36,19000),
    ("Jen","Finance","NY",79000,53,15000),
    ("Jeff","Marketing","CA",80000,25,18000),
    ("Kumar","Marketing","NY",91000,50,21000)
  )
val empDf = emp_seq.toDF("employee_name", "department", "state", "salary", "age", "bonus")
val msgDf = empDf.select($"department", to_json(struct($"employee_name", $"state", $"salary", $"age", $"bonus")).alias("message"))
```

Output

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|department|message                                                                       |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Sales     |{"employee_name":"James","state":"NY","salary":90000,"age":34,"bonus":10000}  |
|Sales     |{"employee_name":"Michael","state":"NY","salary":86000,"age":56,"bonus":20000}|
|Sales     |{"employee_name":"Robert","state":"CA","salary":81000,"age":30,"bonus":23000} |
|Finance   |{"employee_name":"Maria","state":"CA","salary":90000,"age":24,"bonus":23000}  |
|Finance   |{"employee_name":"Raman","state":"CA","salary":99000,"age":40,"bonus":24000}  |
|Finance   |{"employee_name":"Scott","state":"NY","salary":83000,"age":36,"bonus":19000}  |
|Finance   |{"employee_name":"Jen","state":"NY","salary":79000,"age":53,"bonus":15000}    |
|Marketing |{"employee_name":"Jeff","state":"CA","salary":80000,"age":25,"bonus":18000}   |
|Marketing |{"employee_name":"Kumar","state":"NY","salary":91000,"age":50,"bonus":21000}  |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case I would have 3 files sales.json, finance.json and marketing.json with respective message column data.

How would I append existing files and get only the message part of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below steps

**1. Filter the dataframes**

```
val salesDf = empDf.filter(empDf("department") === "Sales")

val financeDf = empDf.filter(empDf("department") === "Finance")

val marketingDf = empDf.filter(empDf("department") === "Marketing")
```

**2. Read existing Sales, finance and marketing files as Df**

```
   val existingSalesDf=spark.read.json("/path/of/existing/json/sales-file")
    
    val existingFinanceDf=spark.read.json("/path/of/existing/json/finance-file")
    
    val existingMarketDf=spark.read.json("/path/of/existing/json/marketing-file")
```

**3. Perform union operation on all sales,finance and marketing dr with their corresponding existing Dataframes**

```
   val appendedSalesDf= salesDf.union(existingSalesDf)

    val appendedFinanceDf=financeDf.union(existingFinanceDf)

    val appendedMarketDf=    marketingDf.union(existingMarketDf)
```